# Data in Firestore resets every time user logs back into the React Native app

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

Every time a user signs out and logs back in, the mood fieldvalue in my firestore database resets to the '' state instead of the mood data that is previously logged in by the user. I want the pre-existing data to not be reset, but also allow the to add on to the pre-existing data. What would be a method to fix this ?

I have below my code for the parts that is related to the above question.

```
const HomeScreen = () => {

  const [mood, setMood] = useState('');


  const uid = auth.currentUser?.uid;
  useEffect(() => {
    firestore.collection('Users').doc(uid).get().then((documentSnapshot) => {
      setMood(documentSnapshot.data().mood);
      console.log('set to: '+ uid)
    });
  }, [uid]);

  firestore.collection('Users').doc(uid).update({
    mood,
    stressLevel,
  });

  const handleSignOut = () => {
    auth
      .signOut()
      .then(() => {
        navigation.navigate('Login')
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        alert(error)
      })
    };

        <IconButton  icon={<Icon as={MaterialCommunityIcons} name="emoticon-frown" />} 
        borderRadius= "full"
        _icon={{color: '#ffcb4c', size: 8}} 
        _hover={{bg: 'coolGray.800:alpha.20'}} 
        onPress={() => setMood(firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(
          ''.concat(0,'  ',format(new Date(), "dd/MM/yyyy 'at' h:mm a"))))
                }
        _pressed={{bg: '#ffcb4c',
        _ios: {_icon: {size: "2xl"}}}} 
        _ios={{icon: {size: "2xl"}}} />
        </View>
```

I tried to troubleshoot and found that removing "mood" from the code below AFTER the usr logs in the data into firebase, keeps the data when the user logs back in. However, the user then is not able to add on to the mood data anymore.

```
firestore.collection('Users').doc(uid).update({
  mood,
  stressLevel,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The fact that `mood` gets set to `''` every time you render this component is caused by this code:

```
const HomeScreen = () => {

  const [mood, setMood] = useState('');

  ...

  firestore.collection('Users').doc(uid).update({
    mood,
    stressLevel,
  });
```

The initial value of mood is `''`, which you then update the database with when the component is constructed.

In general, consider whether you really need this `update` statement to execute when the component is created. Shouldn't it instead run when the user performs an action on the component?

Comment: Without the `update` function, I am not able to push the data into the database upon pressing the icon. I am not sure how I can work around this.